# How to use 1 formControlName for dynamic fields?

Tags: angular

I have a button that adds dynamic input fields.

This is what I have so far:

```
<input id="field" matInput formControlName="field">
```

But for now, this is just static. Let's say we have 3 input fields, then I want the formControlName `field` to be an array.

In HTML you can do it like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="field[]" value="foo">
<input type="text" name="field[]" value="bar">
<input type="text" name="field[]" value="baz">
```

How do you do this in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider declaring the `fields` as `FormArray` element from the beginning itself. And you can keep adding the dynamic input fields inside `FormArray`. Using FormArray you can easily loop over `fields.controls` array to render `field` control.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <button (click)="addField()">Add Fields</button>
  <div formArrayName="fields">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let field of form.get('fields')?.controls">
      <input type="text" [formControl]="field" value="foo" />
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
addField() {
    const fields = this.form.get('fields') as FormArray;
    fields.push(new FormControl());
    console.log(fields)
}
```

[**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ughvwd)